# Fragment Layout Not Adding Up More Views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-nested-fragment

I'm trying to add a `FrameLayout` in my fragment layout, just to reserve space to add another fragment, programmatically. Here's code :

**FRAGMENT XML LAYOUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/detail"
        android:text="" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

But the problem is that, when I'm using `FragmentTransaction` to *replace* the `FrameLayout` with a fragment, it gives an **error:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.platform.apple, PID: 2448
              java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080005 (com.platform.apple:id/fragment_container) for fragment Stopwatch1Fragment{e0be34c #0 id=0x7f080005}
```

Here's the Fragment class code:

**Fragment Class Code**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Stopwatch1Fragment stopwatch1Fragment = new Stopwatch1Fragment();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, stopwatch1Fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    transaction.commit();
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_apple_detail, container, false);
}
```

Now, when I tried using the `R.id.detail` instead of `R.id.fragment_container`, the **Fragment Class** found that `TextView` while when I created another `TextView` after the `FrameLayout` in the **Fragment's xml layout** and tried using it, it still didn't work(Fragment didn't find the view by it's Id). So it seems like, only the *first view*(**R.id.detail**) is working while the **Fragment class** can't find any other added view after that. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make width and  height as match parent in fragment xml layoug like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/detail"
    android:text="" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_content"
    android:layout_height="match_content"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"/>
```

Then intialize fragment programatically like below

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_apple_detail, container, false);

FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Stopwatch1Fragment stopwatch1Fragment = new Stopwatch1Fragment();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, stopwatch1Fragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
transaction.commit();

return root;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to replicate the onCreateViewcode by following

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_apple_detail, container, false);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Stopwatch1Fragment stopwatch1Fragment = new Stopwatch1Fragment();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, stopwatch1Fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    transaction.commit();

    return root;
}
```

Comment: Still not working! I guess the problem is in the layout file. Because `R.id.detail` is working fine but other views aren't.

Comment: Just as a note: I'm running the app on a Nexus 7 Tablet emulator.